# how children's props get updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, still struggling to learn how props get updated and in which lifecycle methods the update takes place. Below is some code I wrote:

```
export default Parent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "Tom"
    }
  }

  changeName = () => {
    this.setState({ name: "Jerry" });
  }
   
  render() {
    return <div>
             <Child name={this.state.name}/>
             <button onClick={this.changeName }>Change Name</button>
          </div>
  }
}
  
  
export default Child extends Component {
  ...
  shouldComponentUpdate(newProps, newState) {
     console.log("old name is" + this.props.name)
     console.log("new name is" + newProps.name)
     return true;
  }

  render() {
     return <p>{this.props.name}</p>
  }
}
```

When I click the button, the content of paragraph changes from "Tom" to "Jerry", which is expected, but if I dig a little bit, the console showed that:

> old name is Tom
>
> new name is Jerry

My question is, after I click the button, inside the `Child` component, `this.props.name` is still `Tom`, which means `this.props` is not the latest props, while inside the `render()` function, `this.props.name` becomes `Jerry`, which means `this.props` is the latest prop.

When did the old prop change to the latest prop? Is there another lifecycle method after `shouldComponentUpdate()` that actually changes `this.props` to the latest props, for example:

```
afterShouldComponentUpdate(newProps, newState){
   ...
   this.props = newProps;
}
```

Does such a lifecycle method exist? I know the name won't match, but is there a lifecycle method that accomplishes the above functionality?

Comment: if you are searching for method: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: You're code above doesn't work. [here](https://codepen.io/macro6461/pen/eYYEdRo) is a working solution as opposed to the class component, [here](https://codepen.io/macro6461/pen/YzzxGPw).

Comment: @MattCroak I might have some typo in my code, which might not work, but that's not the point. I want to know when this.props get updated

Comment: @secondimage The way react works is when a parent's state is passed down to a child component, that is a prop. The child's props update when they are updated in the parent. The life cycle method you're trying to describe above is not a thing.

Comment: you still don't get it bro, check the answer of Aprillion, that's what I'm looking for. so why `this.props.name` is not the lastest name in shouldComponentUpdate() after you click the button, can you explain? isn't that parent also get updated already too?

Comment: @secondimage I get it bro I just didn't know you were specifically referring to `shouldComponentUpdate` in the question you were asking if there was another lifecycle method. In `shouldComponentUpdate`, `nextProps` is the updated props while `this.props` is the old props. `this.props` is old is bc in the context of `shouldComponentUpdate` the props are split into two kinds of values, the current props and the new props. `this.props` is the current props, `newProps` are the updated props. In `render` `newProps` are not a thing there is only `this.props`, which points to the new prop values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such [lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

Assignment of props to `this` is happening BETWEEN lifecycle methods (after `shouldComponentUpdate`, before `render`) by the library itself and there is no *public* interface how you can interfere with the process.